# Finding recursive sum in SQL statement

Tags: sql, algorithm, oracle, recursion

I've two tables A and B like:
`A (id, dep_id)` and `B (id, amount)`

The data in those tables are like this

```
A                 B

id  dep_id        id   amount
--- -------       ---- --------
1   2             1    100    
2   3             2    200
3   NULL          3    300   
4   NULL          4    400
```

The `id` column in table A holds `id` for table B. For a given `id` in table A, there might be a `dep_id` which holds `id` of table B.

The requirement is to calculate the sum of amount of an entry in B and all of its dependent entries. This has to be done in one single sql query. I can't use PL/SQL block for that. Any idea how to do that.

Example:

```
sum(id=1) = 100(id=1,dep_id=2) + 200(id=2,dep_id=3) + 300(id=3) = 600
```

Comment: a bit confused.  Is this a hierarchy? (id=child, dep_id = parent)? Or do I need more coffee?

Comment: You need a DB version that supports `WITH RECURSIVE` to get this in one query. Is that available to you?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus hierarchical queries have been around since Oracle 2 (1978 I believe :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: Use Postgres myself, so not really up on Oracle enhancements. Anyway, it's the way-to-go on this sort of query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help calculating complex sum in hierarchical dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786492/help-calculating-complex-sum-in-hierarchical-dataset)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CONNECT BY ROOT` to build a link of dependency ([hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators004.htm#i1036358)), then aggregate:

```
SQL> SELECT ID, SUM(amount)
  2    FROM (SELECT connect_by_root(a.id) ID, b.amount
  3            FROM a
  4            JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  5           START WITH a.ID = 1
  6           CONNECT BY PRIOR a.dep_id = a.ID)
  7   GROUP BY ID;

        ID SUM(AMOUNT)
---------- -----------
         1         600
```

Additional solutions are available on a similar but slightly more complex schema (for example `id:1` needs 4x`id:2`, which needs 8x`id:3` each) on [this SQL quiz on plsqlchallenge](https://plsqlchallenge.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=10000:659:0::NO:659:P659_QUESTION_ID:7584&cs=10ACC41F64440F00B70EF6E63DEAD95CD&tz=1:00).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Vincents's query you can use:

```
select sum(b.amount) 
from B b 
where b.id in (
    select a.id from A a start with a.id = 1 connect by a.id = prior a.dep_id
);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7d1c/5

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, using a recursive CTE:

```
with recur (id, dep_id, amount)as
(
  select A.id, A.dep_id, b.amount
  from A
  inner join B on A.id = b.id

  union all

  select recur.id, a.dep_id, b.amount
  from recur
  inner join A on recur.dep_id = a.id
  inner join B on a.id = b.id      
)
select id, sum(amount) 
from recur
group by id
```

See working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1c83/2

Answer (score 0):

We can do that using recursive query. I do not have access to the data base, but this is the rough Idea. The query results may not be accurately right,this is in DB2,

```
With Ax as
(
SELECT ID, DEP_ID FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT AX.ID, A.DEP_ID
FROM AX, A
WHERE AX.DEP_ID = A.ID
)

SELECT A.ID, SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM AX AS A JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

The result set for 1 may look like in AX as,

```
1 2
2 3
1 NULL
2 3
3 NULL
4 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a method - cool trick (from a schema with different names - you'll have to adjust)

```
select part_id,  new_rec.quantity*sum(math_calc( math,2)) m, unit_of_measure
from ( SELECT rownum, level lvl, part_id, quantity, unit_of_measure
            , connect_by_isleaf || sys_connect_by_path(quantity,'*') math
from assembly
start with parent_part_id = new_rec.part_id
connect by parent_part_id = prior part_id ) p
group by part_id, unit_of_measure
```

basically - this part

```
connect_by_isleaf || sys_connect_by_path(quantity,'*') math
```

makes a mathematical equation of the summation as a string - then that gets parsed and calculated by this part

```
new_rec.quantity*sum(math_calc( math,2)) m
```