# How to decouple code that generates HTML and does recursive summation in same function?

Tags: php, recursion, refactoring, decoupling

I came across the following code.  It prints out HTML (using `partial` function of ZF2), while also computing total, for all items, recursively.

```
function gen_items($parentId)
{
    $total = 0;
    $rows = $this->db->getData($parentId); //DB call!
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $id = $row['id']
        $price = $row['price'];

        echo $this->partial('item.phtml', array('price'=> $price));

        $total += $price + $this->gen_items($id);
    }

    return $total;
}
```

first, I see this as a problem, because the name `gen_items` makes sense for generating HTML code for line items, but it doesn't make sense for it to sum things.

One thought I have is to make a duplicate function that does all the same things, except one function will be for HTML generation, and one for summation.

**Question**

How can I make this decoupled?  Is it possible to do it without creating essentially two functions that duplicate all the recursive DB calls?

**More Details on DB**

Database structure:  table(id, price);  `id == -1` when there is no parent.  Otherwise, `id` points to parent `id`.

Number of rows - say average about 5-10 parent items, each having 1 to 6 children total (some of it may be i.e. about 3 children with 1 sub-child of its own)

Comment: perhaps to add -- do I make it decoupled in the first place.  Should I?

Comment: Looks like you're querying for the information in the rows to begin with. Why not include in that query some SQL to get the sum of the prices as well?

Comment: may need more info .... I am not too familiar with constructing SQL queries that recursively compute sums, pulling row data recursively....  Plus I will still need individual line item data as well.

Comment: There's a question on that topic if you'd like to do some research. I fear it may be a little far from what would be best in this situation, but please let me know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545467/finding-recursive-sum-in-sql-statement

Comment: I can also, instead of decoupling this, call this function `sum_item_prices`, with a *side-effect* of printing line items in HTML, and leave this as-is, documenting side-effect.

Comment: @mari, thanks that's a cool feature to know.  I'll have to look into it.  I'm on MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pursuing a solution that:

- reads DB recursively
- accumulates rows read from DB in a PHP structure
- provides that structure back to the caller in a nice array

Caller than

- runs iterative algo to print HTML with values from array, and, separately
- sums pricing info.

Voila!

*--- code possibly to be added after it is is written- -

(it's basically same but instead of $total I accumulate $childRows)*